# Pass Form data to another component React Native

Tags: javascript, forms, react-native

I have a form where the inputted data has to be rendered in a different component. I followed a tutorial on Udemy but it did not work really. I have to pass a prop to the child component(form) and render it in the parent(where the Result should be rendered) but without the form being rendered. I tried this so far:

```
 const AddListView = (props) => {
      const [enteredListData, setEnteredData] = useState('');
    
      const listDataHandler = (enteredListData) => {
        setEnteredData(enteredListData);
      }
    
      
    
      return (
        <View style={({ height: 50 }, styles.font)}>
          <Header>
            <Title style={styles.font}>Liste Hinzufügen</Title>
          </Header>
    
          <Card title="Listen Name"> 
            <View>
              <Form>
                <Input
                  onChangeText={listDataHandler}
                  value={enteredListData}
    
                />
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Button
                      round
                     
                      onPress={() => props.onAddList(enteredListData)}
                    >
    </View>
</View>
</View>
```

so onAddlist in on press is my function in the other component here:

```
const [name, setItems] = useState([]);

const addListHandler = listTitle => {
    setItems(currentData => [...currentData,
    {value: listTitle}
    
    ])
    console.log(enteredListData)
    }

<AddListView onAddList={addListHandler}/>

return (
    <View>        
Here it should be rendered but I tried to test it with log but it did not work.
</View>
```

The error I am getting is that my props.onAddlist is not a function. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why your <AddListView/> is not in your return statement?

Comment: The problem is it will be rendered on to the screen then there is a form but I only want the user input displayed not the whole form

Comment: i'm really confused. If you want to just display an input, then why you create a form? And you can just make them one component instead of making a parent-child hierarchy. Also if you need the form, but you don't want to show it, you can use style to hide it and only show user input on the screen.

Comment: Hey I somehow fixed it I can pass data now I do it with react-navigate. But I hav one Problem. The userinput result will be displayed on the main screen which opens when the app is first displayed. If there are no input results currently it should display a string like "It is empty" and when there is an input the result. I tried to do it with if else but it did not work I am getting this error: 
typeerror: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.nameId). My updated code is below.